# RabbitMq consumer does not get another message until it ACKs or NACKs previous message

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have queue in RabbitMq which subscribes to an exchange with results of some computations. One computation can produce several results and I want to process messages containing those results belonging to one computation either all of them or none of them. In case of failure of service none is ACKed so they will be requeued and processed by another instance of service.

My consumer:

```
class ResultConsumer(channel: Channel,
                 private val resultListener: ResultListener)
: DefaultConsumer(channel) {


override fun handleDelivery(consumerTag: String, envelope: Envelope, properties: AMQP.BasicProperties, body: ByteArray) {
    val result = String(body)

    // ....

    if (status != null && status.equals("success")) {
        if (allSubresultsDelivered(result)) {
            channel.basicAck(envelope.deliveryTag, true)
        }
        return
    }
}
```

}

But it does not work because the consumer does not get any other message until it acks (or rejects) previous message.

What is wrong with my code or my understanding?

Comment: It sounds like you really need to group your messages together into one message and process that... or am I missing something? Messages are a continuous stream, so there is no concept of "all of them."

Comment: The messages are results of some computation and each computation can have several subresults and I need to process subresults for one computation together. Grouping them to one message was original idea but is not possible for various reasons.

Comment: What QoS (prefetch) value are you using?

Comment: Messaging is aappropriate when each message represents a finite unit of work. Consumers have no notion of what they’ve processed previously, nor what, if any, message is coming next. If you find yourself in the situation where messages are not independent, then messaging is not the correct tool for the use case.

Comment: I have prefetch=1.

Comment: I agree that this is not good solution and I would prefer sending all results in one message but I am still interested why the consumer does not get another message before acking previous message.

Comment: is your prefetch=1?
that's the reason it only allow one unacked message
increase prefectch count or set it to zero(unlimited)